# What is the correct way to fit text inside LazyVGrid such that the text size is always the same?

Tags: swiftui

I've trying to layout some numbers in a grid

[image]

My goal is that all the text should be of the same size. However I cannot just specify the font size because this view is sized dynamically so a geometryreader is used instead like this:

```
struct OneRow: View {
    let proxy: GeometryProxy
    let columns = [GridItem(.fixed(proxy.size.width * 7 / 15), spacing: 0), GridItem(.fixed(proxy.size.width * 3 / 15), spacing: 0),
                       GridItem(.fixed(proxy.size.width * 3 / 15), spacing: 0), GridItem(.fixed(proxy.size.width * 2 / 15), spacing: 0)]

     var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text(dayWeather.date.formatted(.dateTime.weekday(.abbreviated)))
                .styledText(font: font, color: textColor)
                .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 13 / 15 / 6.5, alignment: .leading)
                .border(.black)

            Text("\(dayWeather.highTemperature.converted(to: temperatureUnit.unitTemperature).weatherFormatted())")
                .styledText(font: font, color: textColor)
                .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 13 / 15 / 6.5, alignment: .leading)
                .border(.black)

            Text("\(dayWeather.lowTemperature.converted(to: temperatureUnit.unitTemperature).weatherFormatted())")
                .styledText(font: font, color: textColor)
                .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 13 / 15 / 6.5, alignment: .leading)
                .border(.black)

            Image(systemName: dayWeather.symbolName)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .imageScale(family == .systemLarge ? .large : .small)
                .foregroundColor(textColor)
                .border(.black)
        }
    }
}
```

At first I attempt to set a fixed width of the Text then I realized that wont work because the length of the text can vary.

Then I change the approach as you can see to fixed height (but even then as you can see the single digit temperature has bigger number than the 2 digits temperature).

What is the correct approach to this grid such that text is always same size but the whole table can be of any size.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? Something that I can copy and paste directly to reproduce your problem. What is `styledText`? Where does `proxy` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use some static text to establish a footprint for a row and then show the actual weather info as an overlay.

The static text should be a placeholder for the widest conceivable data constellation, such as "Wed -00.0° -00.0° Image". A very large font is used to make sure the full width gets filled, then it is scaled to fit the actual width available. This approach ensures that all rows will be scaled by the same amount, because they all have the same size of footprint.

The rows can then be shown in a `LazyVStack` rather than a `LazyVGrid`. To achieve the grid effect, the items in the row should be given a fixed fraction of the width. This is effectively what you were doing before with your `GridItem` definitions.

Since the images can have different aspect ratios, I found it works best to constrain them to a square frame, sized by the height of the row.

This shows it working:

```swift
struct RowData: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let day: String
    let maxTemp: Double
    let minTemp: Double
    let symbol: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let weatherData: [RowData] = [
        RowData(id: 1, day: "Fri", maxTemp: 20.0, minTemp: 7.0, symbol: "sun.max"),
        RowData(id: 2, day: "Sat", maxTemp: 22.0, minTemp: 8.0, symbol: "sun.max"),
        RowData(id: 3, day: "Sun", maxTemp: 19.0, minTemp: 12.0, symbol: "cloud.drizzle"),
        RowData(id: 4, day: "Mon", maxTemp: 18.0, minTemp: 12.0, symbol: "cloud.drizzle"),
        RowData(id: 5, day: "Tue", maxTemp: 20.0, minTemp: 10.0, symbol: "cloud.sun")
    ]

    private func weatherInfo(data: RowData, size: CGSize) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text(data.day)
                .frame(
                    width: size.width * 4 / 15,
                    height: size.height,
                    alignment: .leading
                )
            Spacer()
            Text("\(data.maxTemp, specifier: "%.1f")°")
                .frame(
                    width: size.width * 3.5 / 15,
                    height: size.height,
                    alignment: .trailing
                )
            Text("\(data.minTemp, specifier: "%.1f")°")
                .frame(
                    width: size.width * 3.5 / 15,
                    height: size.height,
                    alignment: .trailing
                )
            Image(systemName: data.symbol)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(
                    width: size.height, // to make it square
                    height: size.height
                )
                .padding(.leading, 10)
        }
    }

    private func rowView(data: RowData) -> some View {

        // Use static text to establish a footprint
        Text("Wed -00.0° -00.0° Image")
            .hidden()

            // Overlay with the visible weather info
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    weatherInfo(data: data, size: proxy.size)
                }
            }
            .font(.system(size: 100))
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
            .scaledToFit()
    }

    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(weatherData) { data in
                rowView(data: data)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(.yellow)
    }
}
```

[image: Weather]

Comment: a genius solution